# Reading UI screen height inside scrollview using GeometryReader

Tags: swiftui

I have a scrollview with a few subviews, and I wanted each of these subviews to have a specific height relative to UI screen height. I know you can do this with GeometryReader, but the moment I put GeometryReader inside ScrollView, it fails to read screen height.

## What I want to achieve

[image: What I want to achieve]

## Code and preview without ScrollView

```
struct CurrentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                        .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, maxHeight: geo.size.height * 0.3)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                        .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, maxHeight: geo.size.height * 0.3)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                        .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, maxHeight: geo.size.height * 0.3)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

## Code and Preview with scrollview

```
struct CurrentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                            .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, maxHeight: geo.size.height * 0.3)
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                            .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, maxHeight: geo.size.height * 0.3)
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                            .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, maxHeight: geo.size.height * 0.3)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The view seems to break whenever I use ScrollView and GeometryReader's height together. I tried putting ScrollView inside GeometryReader, and the other way around as well, but with the same results (geo.size.height becomes 0 it seems).

So is there a way to set frame height relative to screen height for frames inside a scrollview? Or will I have to just resort to `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height` Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you use `maxHeight` instead of `height`. The ScrollView will always try to "collapse" its content and since you are using the GeometryReader to dynamically calculate the height, you need to set it explicitly to tell the ScrollView that this is the size you always want. `minHeight` would also do the trick.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                        .frame(height: proxy.size.height * 0.3)

                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                        .frame(height: proxy.size.height * 0.3)

                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                        .frame(height: proxy.size.height * 0.3)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```